# Why is it that when I put the else statement it immediately returns the value in the else statement?

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

This is the function I created for a list of dictionaries that is this:

```
db = [{'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'c':13, 'd':14, 'e':15}, {'e':25, 'f':26, 'g':27}]
```

When I do the call method like this: it immediately returns what is in the else statement

```
def call(db, key):
    new = []
    for i in range (len(db)):
        if key in db[i]:
            new.append((i, db[i][key]))
        else:
            return []
    return sorted(new)
```

When i take out the else statement it returns the correct result. Why is this the case?

thanks

Comment: Read and use [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Understanding and leveraging the power of debuggin your own code is a skill well worth learning.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your `return` statement inside the for loop will get triggered as soon as you find a dictionary in your `db` variable which does not contain the key - though a later dict in `db` might. (the `return` statement will immediately end a function's execution when it is called)